# Get window list sorted by most recent access bash

Tags: linux, bash, window

I know you can do `wmctrl -l` to list all open windows with their ids.

I would like to have this list sorted by most recent access (the same order as when you do `Alt+Tab`), is they any way with `wmctrl` or with any other command line utilities ?

I'm using xfce4, if you know a way to do it with it

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I don't think it is possible.

getting a list of open windows is easy to export to bash because 
it is manages by the OS.

however, visualizations (such as "windows order") is not managed by the OS.
**Only** the window manager (Explorer for windows, Nautilus for ubuntu, Cinnamon for mint, etc) hold that kind of information. Os can work fine without GUI (using tty only, you can read text, write text, even surf the internet). Windows order means something for the window manager only :(

therefore you either have to access the process memory and parse it or hope for and api exported from the process (which I don't think will happen). Either way you choose, it won't work for more than one specific window manager.
I'm sorry...

Answer (score 1):

xprop -root | grep _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW